# How to find the biggest prime number

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a problem on an educational website platform.
This is the task/problem:

> Write a program that finds and prints the biggest prime number which is `<= N`.
>
> **Input**
>
> On the first line you will receive the number N
>
> **Output**
>
> Print the biggest prime number which is <= N
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 2 <= N <= 10 000 000
>
> **Examples**
>
> If `N=13`, then the biggest prime number is also `13`.
>
> If `N=126`, then the biggest prime number is also `113`.
>
> If `N=26`, then the biggest prime number is also `23`

This is my code, which works fine, but the system does not accept it as fully correct because my code is slow/exceeds the memory limit:

```js
const inputnumber = theNumberN; // Comes dymanically from the system

function getPrimes(max) {
    let sieve = [];
    let primes = [];

    for (let i = 2; i <= max; ++i) {
        if (!sieve[i]) {
            primes.push(i);
            for (let j = i << 1; j <= max; j += i) {
                sieve[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return primes;
}

let result = getPrimes(inputnumber);
let biggest = Math.max(...result);

console.log(biggest);
```

So, how can this be solved?
Can you offer a faster logic/algorithm

Comment: Should probably go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Rather than maintain an array of primes just hold onto the largest found so far. Doing this will take up less memory and save you having to do the final iteration over all primes found.

Comment: How about reversing the for loop and starting at the max and working down to 2 and breaking out as soon as you hit a prime?

Comment: @ReverendDovie He's trying to implement Sieve of Eratosthenes, which requires working up.

Comment: `j <= max` can be `j <= Math.sqrt(max)`

Comment: Inner loop only needs to test for factors below/until the squareroot of j, since every factor will then have a "partner" above the squareroot.

Comment: Don't use `Math.max(...primes)`. They're ordered already - just take `primes[primes.length - 1]`.

Comment: Also, if this is really about performance, https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for **only the biggest prime in a given range** (2 <= N <= 10 000 000), the "simple" approach might actually be faster, since spread in primes below 10 000 000 is preety low (hence, the i-loop won't do so many rotations, disclaimer: this will **not necessarly** be true for all ranges).

```js
function getBiggestPrime(max) {
    let sieve = [];
    let primes = [];
    for (let i = 2; i <= max; ++i) {
        if (!sieve[i]) {
            primes.push(i);
            for (let j = i << 1; j <= max; j += i) {
                sieve[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return primes[primes.length - 1];
}

function getBiggestPrimeTwo(max){
    let biggestPrime = 1;
    for (let i = max; i >= 2; i--){
        let isPrime = true;
        for (let j = 2; j < i; j++){
            if (i % j == 0){ //break the loop, the number is not a prime
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime){
            biggestPrime = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return biggestPrime;
}

function runTests(val, times){
    var t0, t1, res, testStep;
    testStep = val / times;
    t0 = performance.now();
    for (let i = 1; i <= times; i++){
        res = getBiggestPrime(testStep*i);
    }
    t1 = performance.now();
    console.log("Test1: " + res +  ", took: " + (t1-t0) + "msec"); 

    t0 = performance.now();
    for (let i = 1; i <= times; i++){
        res = getBiggestPrimeTwo(testStep*i);
    }
    t1 = performance.now();
    console.log("Test2: " + res +  ", took: " + (t1-t0) + "msec"); 
}

runTests(10000000, 50);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks mate!
The `getBiggestPrimeTwo(max)` function does the job perfectly :)